# XML Schema 1.1: Complex loop relation check

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xpath-2.0, xsd-1.1

this will be a complex question so if you are not absolutely familiar with XML Schema 1.1 you may can not answer this question.

However this validation check is for the XML Schema 1.1 Nerds :)

I have a XML like the following:

```
<HTMLFile filename="N40139">
    <variant>2</variant>
    <overlayTitle>Job Cards</overlayTitle>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <groupTitleBtn>true</groupTitleBtn>
            <name>Removing thermostat</name>
            <src>03-8.2.12.15-10.13.35_MTU_20V8000M91</src>
            <steps>
                <step number="1">
                    <start>0</start>
                </step>
                <step number="2">
                    <start>03</start>
                </step>
                <step number="4">
                    <start>30</start>
                </step>
            </steps>
        </group>
        <group>
            <groupTitleBtn>true</groupTitleBtn>
            <name>Removing thermostat2</name>
            <src>03-8.2.12.15-10.13.35_MTU_20V8000M91</src>
            <steps>
                <step number="1">
                    <start>35</start>
                </step>
                <step number="2">
                    <start>45</start>
                </step>
                <step number="4">
                    <start>55</start>
                </step>
            </steps>
        </group>
    </groups>
</HTMLFile>
```

This is my existing XML Schema to validate this XML:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
vc:minVersion="1.1">

<xs:element name="HTMLVideoMapper">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="HTMLFile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>

                        <xs:element name="variant" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="3"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>

                        <xs:element name="overlayTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

                        <xs:element name="groups" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>

                                    <xs:element name="group" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>

                                                <xs:element name="groupTitleBtn" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                                <xs:element name="src" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>

                                                <xs:element name="steps" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="step" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                    <xs:sequence>

                                                                        <xs:element name="start" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                                                                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                                                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="999"/>
                                                                                </xs:restriction>
                                                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                        <xs:element name="src" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                                                        <xs:element name="end" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                    <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                            </xs:element>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>

                                            </xs:sequence>

                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>

                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>

                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required" />

                    <!-- overlayTitle is not allowed in variant 3 -->
                    <xs:assert test="(variant = 3 or overlayTitle)" />

                    <!-- groups/group/name is not allowed in variant 3 -->
                    <xs:assert test="(variant = 3 or groups/group/name)" />

                    <!-- groups/group/groupTitleBtn is not allowed in variant 3 -->
                    <xs:assert test="(variant = 3 or groups/group/groupTitleBtn)" />

                    <!-- groups/group/steps is not allowed in variant 3 -->
                    <xs:assert test="(variant = 3 or groups/group/steps)" />

                    <!-- in variant 3 only one group is allowed -->

                    <!-- if the group src in two groups is the same,
                    than the nested step-elements of the second group can 
                    not have a smaller value than the last nested step-element 
                    in the first group -->
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However there are three constraints I need to check. I have successfully builded this XML Schema myself but now I came to my limit of experience with it. I could not create the last two comments in the XML Schema as a code.

This are the tasks

1. If the element `variant` has the value 3, then the length of the groups -> group-elements can only be one (one element/object).
2. If the `variant` has the value 1 or 2, than it is necessary to loop over all groups -> group. While iterating we save the `src` value of each `group` in a temporary variable so that we can check in the next `group` if the src is the same. If so, we need to iterate over all steps of this group and the steps of the previous group. Is is only valid that the first `step` `start` elements of the second group is greater than the `step` `start` point of the first group.
3. If the `variant` has the value 1 or 2, then it is again necessary to loop over all groups -> group and the nested `step` elements. Each `start` element of a `step` element must be greater than the previous `step` `start`. So if there is a `step` with attribute `number="1"` and the `start` element of it has the value 3 than the next step with the `number="2"` can only have a `start` `>3`. This is necessary to check.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't explain what it is that you're finding difficult, it's not possible to offer anything except general advice (or just solve your problem for you, which really misses the point).

Your problem appears to be mostly that you are not sure how to express your constraints in XPath.

Let's start with the simple ones you have already written.  The comment says "`overlayTitle` is not allowed in variant 3", which seems to be incompatible with the assertion `(variant = 3 or overlayTitle)`, which would allow

```
<HTMLFile filename="N40139">
  <variant>3</variant>
  <overlayTitle>Job Cards</overlayTitle>
  ...
```

because the XPath or is inclusive, not exclusive.  I think you mean any of

```
if (variant eq 3) then not(overlayTitle) else true()
not(variant eq 3 and overlayTitle)
variant ne 3 or not(overlayTitle)
```

And similarly for the other constraints on variant 3.

For the three constraints you have not yet been able to formulate, I recommend you look at

- the `count()` function (which can tell you how many occurrences of `groups/group` there are)
- quantified expressions (which can check a condition on each instance of `groups/group`, including the complicated ones you describe)
- general value comparisons (which can compare all of the steps descended from $group1 and $group2 to see if any descendants of $group2 are less than or equal to any descendants of $group1:  `$group2//step/start &lt;= $group1//step/start` -- you'll want to negate this, of course).

The validation would be much simpler if there were less redundancy in the XML, of course, and if you gave variants 1, 2, and 3 distinct names.